# PHPUnit autocompletion on Windows

Tags: php, windows, netbeans, phpunit, netbeans-8

NetBeans does not seem to locate the PHPUnit sources, therefore I can not use autocompletion on for instance `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`.

I run PHPUnit from within NetBeans using a `cmd`, on Windows using EasyPHP, generated with:

```
echo @php "%~dp0phpunit.phar" %* > phpunit.cmd
```

Note that this is the recommended way, older variants are not longer supported as I noticed.

Where are the PHPUnit sources located and how can I tell NetBeans to account for support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a workaround:

Install the sources of PHPUnit globally using Composer:

```
composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=4.7.7"
```

And finally add the following path to the include directory of the project:

```
%APPDATA%\Composer\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src
```

This will do the trick. However make sure the installation of PHPUnit and the sources are of the same version to prevent complications.

*Note that the sources can be installed using a lot of different ways, but keep in mind to use the right include directory.*